# Using a fall back to use color instead of background image when on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a fall back in my CSS to change the background image to color instead when using a mobile browser.

Is there a way to set a fall back that will go work when the pixels reach the max-width.

As shown below in my snippet the "media only screen and (max-width: 600px) works when then top body class is not being used.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(https://api.timeforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/final-cover-forest.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  }

input{
    background-color: #03fcd3;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not overriding the `background-image` rule, which is why the image is still showing. You set the background colour, but the background-image is still going to show.

Also, you should add the image in the media query for larger screens instead of removing it in smaller screens - otherwise it could load anyway. Mobile-first is always the  recommended way to go :)

Try this (if you make your browser window small, you will see the blue background):

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;

    /* the rest of the CSS that applies on all screen sizes, e.g.: */
    margin: 0;
    background-size: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

/* Note: we show min 601px because it was max: 600px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(https://api.timeforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/final-cover-forest.jpg);
        /* Add any other CSS for 600+ screens here */
    }
}
```

**Note that the new media query is set at 601px** - you were using max: 600px for small screens so CSS for small screens wil lapply up to *and including* 600px.
Using a mix of `max-width:600px` and `min-width:600px` can cause unexpected behaviour because *both* media queries will apply at 600px.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I should add I didn't get this to work at first but adding `<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in my HTML fixed the issue.

Comment: @ChrisR. Glad to help! I was only testing it in the snippet here by resizing the desktop browser so I didn't think of mentioning that for mobile devices. Its always good practice to include that in your websites anyway so they work properly on mobile :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set two media queries and don’t set background in the beginning.

Initial body background unset

For mobile devices:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   body {
      background-color: lightblue;
   }
 }
```

For computers:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-image: url (https://api.timeforkids.com/wp/content/uploads/2019/09/final-cover-forest.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
  }
}
```